# MessageBox persistence in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, persistence, messagebox

I'm using `MessageBox` to give some information to the user, but when such a box pops up, I want it to block access to the main window. So, until the user has clicked "OK", they should not be able to click (or even focus on) the window that's below it.

Does anybody know how to do this? I've noticed that `MessageBox` has very few functions, so maybe I'll even have to use a different object for this.

Comment: Oh, just after I posted here, my friend came up with the answer. By calling `MessageBox.Show(mf, "text")` where `mf` is the main form, `mf` will be disabled as long as the OK button has not been clicked. I suppose this question was a bit silly to post after all, but I hope it might help others if they're stuck with the same problem.

Comment: There are many questions similar to this (for eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154181/c-net-messagebox-is-not-modal ) so you can delete our question if you got your answer or if you feel it might help others, post the solution as answer and accept it.

Comment: It already works this way.  If you don't specify an owner then it goes hunting for one.  Having it find the wrong one should be very unusual, this only ever goes wrong when you display a message box in a thread.  Which should throw an InvalidOperationException with the debugger attached to remind you that you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after I posted here, my friend came up with the answer. By calling `MessageBox.Show(mf, "text")` where mf is the main form, mf will be disabled as long as the OK button has not been clicked. I suppose this question was a bit silly to post after all, but I hope it might help others if they're stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution could be a dialog form (Project->Add Windows Form->Dialog). This gives you visual extensibility of your MessageBox.

You can call your MessageBox's ShowDialog method and it will of course block access to the parent window.

There are of course other methods.

Example:

```
' This is your Dialog you created by going Project->Add Windows Form->Dialog
Public Class MessageBoxDialog

  Public Overloads Sub ShowDialog(ByVal message As String)

    Me.txtMessage.Text = message

    ShowDialog()

  End Sub
End Class

' This is the form you want to call the message box on
Private Sub btnShowMsgBox_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
                                Handles btnShowMsgBox.Click
    Dim messageBox As New MessageBoxDialog
    messageBox.ShowDialog("This is another way to show a MsgBox but allows greater extensibility.")
End Sub
```

Comment: @Downvoter explain what is wrong with a quick and dirty solution for an already quick and dirty MessageBox call?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the fact that it in no way prevents the user from interacting with other forms, and is thus not a solution to the OP's problem seems likely...

Comment: @jmoreno: Say what? It seems like the op is confused with how the msgbox works but this is an acceptable alternative to the msgbox functionality requested. Note the op did not ask about **other forms** but rather the parent. Perhaps Ive missed something?

Comment: @Maxim, nope, it was me that missed something. So, no I idea why the downvote.