# C# :how to have message box within an event handler that freezes the application until Ok is pressed?

Tags: c#, .net, showdialog

Hi I have this in the main

```
  NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += new NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler(AddressChangedCallback);
//The main also contains a form
```

and this method below it .

```
static void AddressChangedCallback(object sender, EventArgs e){
// would like to have a message box here that freezes the entire application
including  the form as mentioned above , untill OK is pressed"
}
```

Comment: What do you use? WPF, WinForms? Did you try `MessageBox.Show`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a WinForms application. `NetworkAddressChanged` event is invoked on a background thread. This is why when you display a message box from there your app stays active.

Solution 1:
You need to marshal this call to your main UI thread. You can do this by using **[Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)** method on your main form. Define a method on the form class to show message box. Call this method using Invoke method on your main form.

Solution 2:
[C# / .NET messagebox is not modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154181/c-net-messagebox-is-not-modal)

Comment: hi zespri ... its a  a plain  console application . Is it possible to do the same as you suggested .. ?

Comment: @HelloWorld_Always: In you question you say "The main also contains a form". What do you mean by this if it's not WinForms?

Comment: @HelloWorld_Always: Consider accepting the answer if it satisfies you.

Answer (score 0):

It is called modal and modeless. Show is modeless, ShowDialog is modal. You can read more [here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-US/library/39wcs2dh%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: MessageBox class produces a message box that is always modal relative to its parent. This is different from showing *forms* in modal mode.

Comment: @Zespri : ShowDialog allows to specify the parent when showing forms.