# Message box in C# appears sometimes otherwise its seen in the taskbar

Tags: c#

Currently in my application the Message box is seen sometimes correctly, In some instances seen in the taskbar which shouldn't happen.

```
if (!flag)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Fileds Cannot be empty. Please follow the format", "Message");

   return false;
}
```

Comment: this *should* never happen (I mean appearance in taskbar). Are you sure that actually *this* MessageBox appears there ?

Comment: can you show those 2 screenshots

Comment: sorry it appears in the toolbar

Comment: Now currently its is hiding under the main window

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may need to set the owner property of the MessageBox, answered by @Charlie in this post [C# / .NET messagebox is not modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154181/c-net-messagebox-is-not-modal)

To do this use the MessageBox.Show(IWin32Window, String, String) method, details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y3c0fky.aspx