# C# .NET & Messageboxes the user cant ignore

Tags: c#, .net, controls, message, messagebox

So I have failed to find anything that works...

But what I want a messagebox that wont allow the user to do ANYTHING untill he or she has clicked ok.

So if they were to say...Click outside the message box. it would beep and blink at them untill ok is clicked.

Is this done through the properties on the left hand side for the main parent form? Or is this all done through programming?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Can't do anything inside your app or anything with their computer at all? The former should be easy enough, the latter probably not.

Comment: Nothing lol. Hope this can happen the way i hope so. Thanks for your input

Comment: Why the down votes? Simple question? Yes, but still valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Show the window using the .ShowDialog() method.

Comment: Ill give this a try. Thank you for the quickness of your reply. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154181/c-net-messagebox-is-not-modal), but in a nutshell, you need to set the MessageBoxOwner property to the main UI window.

Comment: Ill check that. Mind helping me here. Whats modal? Have a link that can explain that or maybe you? Thanks a ton for your help

Comment: A 'modal window' is simply a dialog that requires the  user to interact with it before the user can resume using the parent application.